# Framework para criar um editor de imagens em C#

Tags: imagem, processamento-de-imagens

Sou iniciante em c# e gostaria de criar um editor de imagens no estilo do Libresprite, em que posso customizar a UI da forma que quiser.
Se for possível gostaria de conhecer os melhores frameworks ou ferramentas para criar esse editor de imagens.